# Visual Studio Code ssl connection to MySQL Server

Tags: mysql, ssl, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I've tried every available package, and none will allow me to connect to the campus MySQL server which requires ssl.  However, I can connect using terminal and the `mysql` command, and I can also connect using `MySQLWorkbench`. I did not specify any "ssl" anything for either of these.

What am I doing wrong in Visual Studio Code?

Comment: Are you creating a new extension which needs to connect to a MySQL Server via ssl, or are using existing extensions?